# Office 365 Development

Tags: office-365, exchange

I need to develop app on office 365 "School management app"

I want to publish my app in Office Store so I must use SharePoint hosted app but I can't use SharePoint autohosted app, is it true?

If I use an SharePoint hosted app, how can I use API to access Office resources such as mail, calender and Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Provider Hosted app or SharePoint hosted app. Auto-hosted is no more, so stay away from that path.

In your situation I would use a Provider Hosted app, and use the [Office 365 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605893%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (though it is still in Preview..) to interact with mail and calendar in Office 365. A get started guide here: http://zimmergren.net/technical/getting-started-with-office-365-development-part-1-setting-up-your-environment

If not Office 365, you can use the "normal" C# ways of interacting with Exchange in your provider hosted app (basic example here http://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=2)

Comment: Updated with some good starting points

Comment: thanks a lot for your replay,
Provider Hosted app i can publish in office store ?
so, can i add Office 365 APIs in Provider Hosted app to access office resources such as mail and calender ?

Comment: Yes, and yes you can